# Linear Differentiation Question

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find the general solution to the following differential equation.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{8y}{9} $$

These are the possible answers given...

(A) $y = e^{(9/8)x} + C$

(B)  $y = x^{8/9} + C$

(C)  $y = Ce^{(8/9)x}$

(D)  $y = Cx^{8/9}$

(E)  $y = Ce^{(9/8)x}$

(F)  $y = Cx^{9/8}$

(G)  $y = e^{(8/9)x} + C$

(H)  $y = x^{9/8} + C$

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know of the method of separating variables?

Comment: You can find the derivative of these given possible answers if you not able to solve the ODE

Comment: Use separation of variables. Move the $y$ term to the L.H.S. and integrate, this should give a nice explicit equation for the solution after some algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [separable ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx). Try separating the variables by dividing both sides by $y$, then integrating both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{8y}{9}$$
$$\frac{1}{y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{8}{9}$$
$$\int \frac{1}{y}~dy=\int \frac{8}{9}~dx$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Ohhhhhh okay! yes i can go from here thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to tell us on the comments which one of the answers you get, and I can tell you if it is correct or not.

Comment: I got C as the answer

Comment: @NoahI Yes, well done! That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We have,

$\frac 1y dy = \frac 89 dx$

Now on integration,

$\log y = \frac 89 x + \log c$

$\log y - log c = \frac 89 x$

Hope you can proceed now.